# Get all users from azure AD group SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am currently trying to use a people picker to be able to get user properties and if a group is picked I want to be able to get all the user keys.

I can get all the properties I need if I select a user and I have managed to get all the users that are in the SharePoint groups. Now I am trying to get all the users that are in the azure ad groups. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

There's no support for Azure AD groups in either the Client Object Model or the SharePoint REST API. Using the Microsoft Graph is a problem because configuring Reply URLs for a SharePoint-hosted App is a real pain.

My suggestion is that you use Microsoft Flow. You can create a Flow with a HTTP Request trigger. The Flow then basically becomes a web service.

[image: Complete Flow]

[image: Request Trigger]

You can then use the Azure AD - Get group members action to get the members from the group.

[image: Get group members]

Finally you can use the Response action to return the array of user object returned from the Get group members action.

[image: Response action]

Once the Flow is done you can then call this Flow in pretty much the same way you would call the SharePoint REST API.

[image: Calling the Flow]